# Json undefined problema con mostrar los valores

Tags: javascript, html, json, nodejs, mongodb

Buenas tardes tengo un problema, trate de recuperar los datos de mi api, que son en este caso las ordenes, las ordenes, la estructura JSON es de esta manera:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5fd3b576d6da3d00092d7fe1",
    "platillo_id": "5fd3080505d75349d0f886e2",
    "usuario_id": "Fabricio Guzman",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Quiero hacer que el usuario así como platillo_id se muestren (con este tambien tengo problema) se plasmen en la pantalla, solo que me sale como undefined, se que quizas sea un error tonto pero la verdad estoy cansado y me bloque.

El codigo que tengo es de esta manera.

```
fetch('https://pedidos-d7p859czq.vercel.app/api/ordenes')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log("data", data);
        console.log("data", platillosState);
        ordenState = data;
        const listaOrden = document.getElementById('ordenes');
        const plantillaOrden = [data].map(mostrarOrden);
        listaOrden.removeChild(listaOrden.firstElementChild);
        plantillaOrden.forEach(element => listaOrden.appendChild(element));
    });

    const mostrarOrden = (itemOrden) => {
    console.log("item",itemOrden);
    const elementoOrden = stringtoHTMLOrden(`<li data-id='${itemOrden._id}' class="list-group">${itemOrden.usuario_id}</li>`);
    return elementoOrden;
};

    const stringtoHTMLOrden = (cadena) => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(cadena, 'text/html');
    return doc.body.firstChild;
}
```

Otro punto que me gustaría hacer es que recupere datos de platillo, su estructura JSON es de esta manera.

```
 [
  {
    "_id": "5fd307d48e33fc2b0024492c",
    "nombre": "Hamburgesa",
    "desc": "Hawaiana",
    "precio": "58.00",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

La variable que trate de usar para hacer que el JSON se guarde se llama platillosState, pero no puedo hacer que este se logre mostrar.

Comment: Indica en qué línea ocurre el error de _undefined_ para que te puedan ayudar más fácilmente.

Comment: Si el data que te devuelve la api es en si una array, ¿Por que lo metes dentro de otra array para hacer el `map`? `[data].map(mostrarOrden)`